# Postgres: why does to_timestamp return the date with different timezones, in the same query?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, timezone

Why does `to_timestamp` use different timezones to display epochs, in the same query? Note `+02` vs `+01`.

```
=> select to_timestamp(1651157248),to_timestamp(1647224832);
      to_timestamp      |      to_timestamp      
------------------------+------------------------
 2022-04-28 16:47:28+02 | 2022-03-14 03:27:12+01
(1 row)

=> select version();
                                                                version                                                                 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 12.12 (Ubuntu 12.12-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0, 64-bit
(1 row)

=> show timezone;
   TimeZone    
---------------
 Europe/Vienna
(1 row)
```

It may be related to the switch from winter to summer time at the end of March, with `+01` corresponding to `CET` and `+02` to `CEST`.

How do I use `to_timestamp` such that it uses consistently the same time offset (no matter which one)?

Comment: You should have declared those columns as `timestamp` instead of the [dreaded epoch](https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/epoch-mania/) then you wouldn't have that problem now.

Comment: but you are right: April, 28 is CEST and March 14 is CET, so the result is correct.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Not sure I understand. The contents of this column is external data: A float giving the epoch of the event. I used `\copy` to get the csv data into the table. How would I have to read the data such that it is more convenient to use? In my experience, it is a tradeoff between the ease of getting the data into the database and the manipulations afterwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Austria has daylight savings time, so PostgreSQL will display timestamps in winter with a different UTC offset than timestamps in spring.  `to_timestamp` converts an UTC epoch to a (time zone independent!) `timestamp with time zone`. Only when the `timestamp with timezone` is rendered as string, this is done according to the current setting of `timezone`.

All your timestamps are displayed in the same time zone: `Europe/Vienna`. This time zone has different offsets from UTC at different times of the year. If you want all timestamps shown with the same UTC offset, choose a `timezone` setting that has no daylight savings time, for example `UTC` or `+02`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I understand that `to_timestamp` shows the `timestamp with timezone`, and apparently chooses the timezone depending on the timezone set and the winter/summer time at the time of the timestamp. I do not understand what you mean by *Only when ...*. Isn't this what my example does, displaying the timestamps as strings? How would I have to reformulate the expressions such that both timestamps are shown with the same timezone?

Comment: You understood correctly: the timestamps *are* rendered as strings, so `timezone` is respected. All timestamps are displayed in the same time zone!

Comment: Please check the example that I give above: The timestamps are *not* displayed in the same time zone. This is exactly the point of my posting: How to display them in the same time zone, with the same offset?

Comment: Oh yes, they are displayed in the same time zone. But they are displayed with different time zone offset. As I wrote, if you want the same offset for all, use a different `timezone` setting.

Answer (score 1):

`to_timestamp` displays an epoch according to the currently set time zone, with an appropriate offset. If the time zone happens to have a daylight saving time (DST), then the offset chosen depends on whether the epoch falls into the range of the DST or not. For the examples below, observe that on `2022-03-27 02:00:00+01`, the time zone `CET` switched from standard time to DST.

```
=> set time zone 'CET';
=> select to_timestamp(1648342799) t,to_timestamp(1648342799+1) "t+1s";
           t            |          t+1s          
------------------------+------------------------
 2022-03-27 01:59:59+01 | 2022-03-27 03:00:00+02
```

To obtain identical offsets, either set the time zone to one without accompanying DST:

```
=> set time zone 'UTC';
=> select to_timestamp(1648342799) t,to_timestamp(1648342799+1) "t+1s";
           t            |          t+1s          
------------------------+------------------------
 2022-03-27 00:59:59+00 | 2022-03-27 01:00:00+00
```

or specify the time zone explicitly each time you display an epoch:

```
=> select to_timestamp(1648342799) at time zone 'CET' t,to_timestamp(1648342799+1) at time zone 'CET' "t+1s";
          t          |        t+1s         
---------------------+---------------------
 2022-03-27 01:59:59 | 2022-03-27 02:00:00
```